# Retrieving DHCP-allocated domain suffix in Linux C

Tags: c, linux, dns, network-programming

I'm trying to retrieve the local domain suffix of my host programmatically in ANSI C (Linux).  Eg: my machine is ironside.0ffnet.net, I'd like to retrieve "0ffnet.net".

I've seen a number of posts addressing this by using getnameinfo() and getaddrinfo(), however it appears that these functions pull their information from the /etc/hosts file for any interface addresses local to the machine.

If my machine is allocated an address (and corresponding domain suffix) via DHCP, the /etc/hosts file does not get updated, instead this information is stored in /etc/resolv.conf e.g.:

```
dfex@ironside:~/hush$cat /etc/resolv.conf 
domain 0ffnet.net
search 0ffnet.net
nameserver 139.130.4.4
```

as a result, both getnameinfo() and getaddrinfo() simply return the hostname of the machine, without the suffix, using the /etc/hosts info, which looks like:

```
dfex@ironside:~/hush$ cat /etc/hosts
::1             ironside localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
127.0.1.1       ironside
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
```

Does anybody know of a function that will pull this information without resorting to system() calls?  I've been combing through Beej's guide without much success.

Comment: You probably has to do a proper DHCP broadcast. See [RFC2131](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt) for the actual protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have to break this question apart and answer the parts separately. First the title question.

### DHCP domain

The only way to really know what the DHCP client has received from the DHCP server is to read the files that the client has left in `/var/lib/dhcp`. The search domain suggested by DHCP might not be used at all, if something else has taken control of `resolv.conf`.

### "the local domain suffix of my host"

A host may belong to several domains, or none, making this a hard concept to define. `resolv.conf` specifies domains that will be searched for hostnames that you are resolving; there's no fundamental guarantee that the search will be successful when applied to your *own* hostname.

### Whatever! The resolver search list is what I really want. How do I get it?

Call `res_init` and then look at `_res.dnsrch` and/or `_res.defdname`. Or parse `resolv.conf` yourself; it's a pretty simple and stable format.

### Then what is getdomainname() for?

It's for NIS(YP), which you probably don't want.

Comment: Legend - thanks Alan - hadn't come across res_init before.  That did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use:

```
int getdomainname(char *name, size_t len);
```

Try to run this program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 char buf[255];
 getdomainname(buf, 255);
 printf("Domain: %s\n", buf);
 return 0; 
}
```

EDIT:

Nope, after many tries I suspect you'll have to use a syscall and an ugly C parser (using AWK inside the `popen` would have made this code a little bit shorter).

This code seems to work for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 char buf[255];
 const char reqhostname[255] = "ENTER_YOUR_HOSTNAME_HERE";

 FILE *fd;
 char readbuf[255];
 char *pch;
 int token_counter = 0;

 memset(buf, 0, 255);
 strcat(buf, "host ");
 strcat(buf, reqhostname);
 fd = popen(buf, "r");
 fgets(readbuf, 255, fd);
 printf("Host returned: %s\n", readbuf);
 pclose(fd);

 pch = strtok(readbuf, " ");
 while (pch != NULL)
   {
        strcpy(buf, pch);
        break;
   }

 memset(buf2, 0, 255);
 pch = strtok(buf, ".");
 while (pch != NULL)
   {
        pch = strtok(NULL, ".");
        if (pch == NULL)
           {
                memset(buf, 0, 255);
                strncpy(buf, buf2, strlen(buf2) - 1);
                break;
           }
        token_counter++;
        strcat(buf2, pch);
        strcat(buf2, ".");
   }

 printf("Domain: %s\n", buf);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be trying the same source - the output I get from the above is: Domain: (none)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @alan-curry that definitely pointed me in the right direction.  For anyone else struggling with this, res_init is definitely the way to go.  Here's a quick way to get the local domain suffix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <resolv.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

res_init();

printf ("Default domain: %s\n", _res.defdname);
return 0;
}
```